# JQuery UI Autocomplete widget not working on a bootstrap modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a bootstrap modal dialog on which I have a textbox that I want to leverage the functionality of jQuery UI Autocomplete widget. However the autocomplete widget isn't being fired at all. I know this as I placed a breakpoint on the action on my controller that should return the Json to be rendered by the autocomplete textbox. The action is never hit

Out of curiosity that I was doing something wrong, I copy pasted the textbox onto a View and to my dismay, the breakpoint on my action in the controller is hit. I have narrowed this down to the fact that may be  the textbox is never wired to use the autocomplete feature once the DOM has loaded. 
Here is the textbox on my modal

```
 <input type="text" name="someName" id="autocomplete" data-autocomplete-url="@Url.Action("Autocomplete", "warehouses")" />
```

Here is the action method that returns the Json

```
public ActionResult Autocomplete(string term)
    {
        string[] names = { "Auma", "Dennis", "Derrick", "Dylan", "Mary", "Martha", "Marie", "Milly", "Abel", "Maria", "Bergkamp", "Arsene", "Alex", "Mwaura", "Achieng" };
        var filtered = names.Where(a => a.IndexOf(term, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
        return Json(filtered, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And here is how I wire up the textbox to use the autocomplete widget

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    source: $(this).data('autocomplete-url'),
    data: {term: $(this).val() }
});
```

});

I have seen similar questions asked but none of them was due to the action not being hit.

Comment: instead of `$(this).data('...` try `$('#autocomplete').data('...` and look for any errors in console.

Comment: there is no need of `data: {term: $(this).val() }` as autocomplete will automatically do this for you.

Comment: I have tried changing to $('#autocomplete') but there are no errors on the console. I also removed the data:{term: $(this).val() } but there is no difference. If I just copy the textbox to a view and try typing a letter, I get the results. This means the problem is having it on the Modal dialog

Comment: Are you displaying some div from your main page inside modal or you are displaying partial view inside modal??..if you are displaying partial inside modal then write this code inside partial instead of main view.

Comment: My modal doesn't display markup from  a Partial View, I set the html for the modal inside it without calling a partial View.

Comment: When is you modal shown ? You need to write following code after modal is shown. `$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    source: $(this).data('autocomplete-url'),
    data: {term: $(this).val() }
});`

Comment: how are you setting content of your modal, is the modal present on page load, or are you setting it's content from an ajax request

Answer (score 3):

As per the documentation for [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events), they expose a set of events that you can hook into with most of their JS features.

In this case the events are: 
**show, shown, hide, hidden and loaded**

The following code will initialize your autocomplete input field after the modal has been shown. (replace myModal with the id of the modal you are going to show)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

    $("#autocomplete').autocomplete('destroy'); //remove autocompete to reattach
    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
      source: $(this).data('autocomplete-url'),
      data: {term: $(this).val() }
    });

  });
});
```

If you are fetching a partial that contains the input field and appending it to the modal during the toggle, it will be better to do this initialization in the callback from that ajax request.